# Call from external server, Google Apps Script published as Web App with restrictions Anyone in the domain

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a GAS that can be called in POST mode by an external server (not by user, so we talk about server-to-server)

The doPOST function of the script performs an action only on the Google Drive of the owner of the script (creates a document based on the parameters passed by the POST and move another file)

Everything works correctly if the script published as Web App, is set as "who has access to the app = public (no login required)"
Obviously in this case the server making the call has no problems.

If instead the script is set as "who has access to the app = anyone in the domain xxx" then the call must be authenticated in some way.

So, a normal POST call that previously no need authentication parameters, now needs to be authenticated ... but how? I was unable to find documentation about it

My reasoning is as follows (but it is not said that it is right):

- do I need an OAuth2 Token? : No, because the Script that is set to “run as me” has already received the authorization token, in fact with "who has access to the app = public (no login required)" everything works correctly.
- so I just have to be recognized as “someone from the xxx domain” … maybe I just need to create an API Key and use it in the Header of the POST call For example: "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey

unfortunately it doesn't work, I point out that I have already moved the Script from Apps Script–managed Cloud Platform project to Standard GCP Project and API credentials with which I tried, were created in the same project.

thanks to anyone who can help me!

Comment: You'd need access token identifying the user calling the script as someone from your domain. [This](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) may help. You'd need drive access scope at minimum.

Comment: Read [this](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script).

Comment: Both of the comments provided a very useful information. Has this solved your problem?